# BasicAuth enabled CORS requests on IE8/9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cors

So, this happened. Quick bullet point list of facts:

- I have a HAL backend that lives on a different subdomain but (thankfully for IE10 support) in the same domain as my web app.
- I need POST and GET requests made.
- I do not need support for IE7 or less.
- I NEED support for IE8 and up.
- The way the API is built, I need to both send custom headers and be able to access the response headers. One of them is the basicAuth headers, but there may be more (like Location response headers and whatnot).
- I am well aware of the limitations of the XDomainRequest object.
- I have full control of both the API and the web app servers, code and everything in between. Yet, we believe the API is well built and shouldn't change because of one browser's poor implementation, so we'd like to keep changes to it at a minimum.

So that's how things are going. So far, I've checked a few alternatives that do not work. Here's a list of them and why it wouldn't help in this case:
 - JSONP, it only allows GET requests.
 - easyXDM, it does not allow custom headers to be sent.
 - OpenAjax Hub, documentation seemed confusing and scarce, but it seems that it has no support for custom headers either.

So here's the question: is there any solution I am missing? My only hope right now is to build a custom swf and override jQuery's $.ajax function to be able to use it as a transport, but am unsure if it'll work. In theory, it should. In practice... well, that's another matter entirely. SO before delving in the depths of swf hell, I thought I might ask if anyone ever faced this problem before and have any form of advice?

Comment: If you have control over both servers, CORS shouldn't be a problem provided you add the appropriate Access-Control-* headers to request/response pairs.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp You can't send custom headers with your cross-origin ajax requests in IE8 or IE9 due to the limitations of the cross-origin  ajax transport in these browsers: `XDomainRequest`.  Look at the answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an embedded iframe, whose src lives on the other domain, and using window.postMessage to go back and forth between the two windows, where the embedded iframe does all of the XHR for your subdomain, and then sends back a custom-wrapped response with all of the header/data you would typically see in CORS.

You'll then have your IE8/9 support.

Comment: Here is a nifty implementation of this concept: https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

Comment: So far, this seems like a good option. I'm trying to go with @RayNicholus, but am kinda worried because I'm using Backbone and I've patched the sync method with quite a few things. I'll let you guys know how it goes! Thank you!

Comment: @enrique-ramirez It's really your only option (short of changing your interface, to remove custom-headers and using the XDomainRequest).  Whether you use a pre-built library, or do IE-tests (testing for XDomainRequest (IE10/11 take a hit, but at least they all work), and changing your interface to set up iframes, et cetera) is the solution you must use (again, short of changing your API). What you really need to decide between is whether you write an IE-specific wrapper for your client-side, and use CORS elsewhere, or just use iframes all over the place.

Comment: @Norguard Seems like it (swf route seems way too... ugly and insecure). I'm trying an IE-only polyfill (this feels like quite an ugly hack to be used everywhere). Am currently awaiting deployment to our staging enviroment to properly check IE, since it seems it's having some issues with self-signed certificates. Will accept your answer once I can get a nice rundown on how things went! Thanks again!